# How to make vector length look better?

Tags: arrows, brackets, vector

How to make it look better:

[image]

Code:

```latex
    $$\left|\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\right|^2=\left|\overrightarrow{a}\right|^2+\left|\overrightarrow{b}\right|^2-2\left|\overrightarrow{a}\right|\left|\overrightarrow{b}\right|\cos(\alpha)$$
```

The |a| looks awful...

Comment: don't use `\left\right` just use `\lvert ..\rvert` (also don't use `$$` in latex)

Comment: I'd use `\lvert \vec{a} \rvert`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion it's hopeless to get “good looking” expressions involving `\vec`.

First of all, you should never use `$$` and very sparingly `\left` and `\right`, which in this case produce oversized delimiters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\vcc}{\mspace{1mu}}% vector correction

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
\left|\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\right|^2=
\left|\overrightarrow{a}\right|^2+\left|\overrightarrow{b}\right|^2
-2\left|\overrightarrow{a}\right|\left|\overrightarrow{b}\right|\cos(\alpha)
\\
\left|\vec{a}-\vec{b}\right|^2=
\left|\vec{a}\right|^2+\left|\vec{b}\right|^2
-2\left|\vec{a}\right|\left|\vec{b}\right|\cos(\alpha)
\\
\lvert\vec{a}-\vec{b}\rvert^2=
\lvert\vec{a}\rvert^2+\lvert\vec{b}\rvert^2
-2\lvert\vec{a}\rvert\,\lvert\vec{b}\rvert\cos(\alpha)
\\
\lvert\vec{a}-\vec{b}\vcc\rvert^2=
\lvert\vec{a}\vcc\rvert^2+\lvert\vec{b}\vcc\rvert^2
-2\lvert\vec{a}\vcc\rvert\,\lvert\vec{b}\vcc\rvert\cos(\alpha)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

(1) is your input.

(2) is the same, but with `\vec` instead of `\overrightarrow`.

(3) uses `\lvert` and `\rvert` (which are recommended over the bare `|`).

(4) adds a tiny space before the closing delimiter; this space is not generally needed after `\vec{<letter>}`, but it's better when a fence follows, to avoid clashes. See later.

In (3) and (4) I also added `\,` between the consecutive `\rvert` and `\lvert`, so the reader doesn't mistake the symbol for `\Vert`.

[image]

Compare the output of `(\vec{a}+\vec{b})` and `(\vec{a}+\vec{b}\vcc)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll take it for the future. Can you please explain why i should nver use `$$`? By the moment i use `$$` for short expresions, and `\begin{gather*}` for long to be able make new line by `\\\`.

Comment: @VladyslavRehan See [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Using fixed size | and fixed height arrows, squeezing *b* so it's not excessively high on *a*

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\xvec[1]{\vec{\rule{0pt}{1.3ex}\smash{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\[
\lvert\xvec{a}-\xvec{b}\rvert1^2=\lvert\xvec{a}\rvert^2+
\lvert\xvec{b}\rvert^2-
2\lvert\xvec{a}\rvert\lvert\xvec{b}\rvert\cos(\alpha)
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you (a) get rid of all `\left` and `\right` sizing directives, (b) apply a consistent height for the arrows, and (c) load the [old-arrows](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/old-arrows) package for smaller arrowheads.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \lvert and \rvert macros
\usepackage{old-arrows}  % uncomment for smaller arrowheads
\newcommand\ab{a\vphantom{b}}
\begin{document}

%\[
%  \left|\overrightarrow{a}-\overrightarrow{b}\right|^2
% =\left|\overrightarrow{a}\right|^2
% +\left|\overrightarrow{b}\right|^2
%-2\left|\overrightarrow{a}\right|
%  \left|\overrightarrow{b}\right| \cos(\alpha)
%\]

\[
  \lvert \overrightarrow{\ab}-\overrightarrow{b}\rvert^2
 =\lvert \overrightarrow{\ab}\rvert^2
 +\lvert \overrightarrow{b}\rvert^2
-2\lvert \overrightarrow{\ab}\rvert
  \lvert \overrightarrow{b}\rvert \cos(\alpha)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for not staying on the sidelines and offering something. I'll take that into consideration for the future.